# Angular how to change devServer hostname?

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

i have an Asp.Net Core 6 project with two Angular 14 apps. The first app is available at https://localhost:44313/. The second app is available at https://localhost:44313/clientapp2 and it reloads every time. I can fix it by adding "ng serve --live-reload" but that's a bad way. I need to change DevServer webSocketURL "wss://localhost:44313/ng-cli-ws" to "wss://localhost:44313/clientapp2/ng-cli-ws".
How can i do this?

Sample project on [github](https://github.com/alkoval/AspNetCoreMultipleAngular).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
ng serve --serve-path /ws
```

it will be like:

```
ws://localhost:4600/ws/ng-cli-ws
```